# Controlling ATX power with HAP-NodeJS

Tags: raspbian, gpio

I want to control my PC power via the ATX headers on the mainboard. To trigger power and reset events the two corresponding pins on the mainboard have to be short circuited i believe. Can i achieve this with the gpio command in Rapsbian please?

Edit: I've decided to try to use the [MAX320](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/256/MAX320-MAX322-103198.pdf) analogue switch for the purpose. Would this work?

Thanks
Maciej

Comment: Your correct on the short circuit thing. But I don't think that is the way to go. A better idea might be to make use of the wake-on-LAN t feature that nearly all modern computers have. What this means is when a certain packet of data is sent to the computer through the Ethernet port it will turn on. I believe this might even work if the computer is turned off  but still has power to it.

Comment: And how do i cut power to it if it hangs? Please provide proper answers to the actual question instead of suggestions to do something completely different. Thanks.

Comment: The chance of your computer hanging (I would hope) is relatively small. The suggestion I gave avoided this idea of shorting connectors on a motherboard, which is much more likely to go wrong. An alternative would be to think about how to control the power button on the computer with the Pi. I.e a circuit which when activated by the Pi pushes the power button. I'm giving suggestions because I don't always necessarily have the time to give full answers. And my goal isn't always to spoon feed people answers but to push them in the right direction.

Comment: The whole purpose is to be able to reboot it when it hangs.

Comment: The best thing to do at a guess would be to link to the motherboard header switch (like the power button). This can be done through jumper wires, will largely work alongside your existing PC power switch and not override the motherboard's control of the power supply. The power supply version can work but would he bad if thats how you want to shut the computer down

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Raspberry Pi to control PC's power switch](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13989/use-raspberry-pi-to-control-pcs-power-switch)

Answer (score -1):

You can see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03J497Pmve4 Sensorless part, and then connect the green cable and ground from the power supply to the relay pin Base and NO

Comment: Could you add the instruction here please in case the video cant be found?